# how to read a json file record by record

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How can i make a for each loop for each record in my json file  using Json.Net ?

my json file is something like this :

```
{
    "transactions":[
        {
            "type":"deposit",
            "account_id":123456789012345,
            "amount":20000.0
        },
        {
            "type":"deposit",
            "account_id":555456789012345,
            "amount":20000.0
        },
        {
            "type":"payment",
            "account_id":123456789012345,
            "amount":20000.0
        },
        {
            "type":"transfer",
            "from":555456789012345,
            "to":123456789012345,
            "amount":20000.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Update :

I want to read each record .... and then Deserializing that record (record in the foreach loop) and put "type","account_id" etc to some other strings

and i want to make a loop that read the record one by one (not all of them in once)

/////////////////////////

Update 2 :

I want a code like this :

```
    dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(file);

foreach (var obj in jsonObj)
{

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to read it line by line? Have you searched at SO before asking this question?

Comment: You definitely want to research 'json deserialization' before leaving this question here.  For example: http://goo.gl/i5KYsh

Comment: I want to read it record by record (I edit the topic). I want to read the record one by one and Analysis that record.

Comment: @Pedram_Parsian analyze how?  JSON.NET just take sin an enitre string and deserializes it to an object (which might be a collection of other objects).  Can you not just iterate the collection after it's deserialized?

Comment: Manually parsing a json string is generally not a good idea. Is there a reason you want to parse the string and deserialize the objects one at a time instead of deserializing the entire string and iterating the objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure why this hasn't already come up, so maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you should be able to do something like this.

```
var fileJson = JToken.Parse(file);

foreach (var item in fileJson["transactions"])
{
    // do stuff
}
```

That might have a missing cast in it, it's been a little while since I wrote any serialization code, but that should be the gist of it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It Works but for example : I have 4 record in above example but it works 5 Time ! why ? what is wrong ?

Comment: @Pedram_Parsian You mean it's iterating through an unexpected element? What is that element? If you look at `item.ToString()` for each of them then it should be pretty clear if it's hitting an unexpected one.

Comment: thank you. it also solve. but , as you see in my sample json file above the amount is "20000.0" but when I use MessageBox.Show(item["amount"].ToString()); code it does not show ".0" at the end. why ?

Comment: That string in your JSON is a number type (it isn't surrounded by quotes), so when it's parsed by JSON.net, it's parsed as a number. You could always use a custom format to map out that extra decimal place. If you need to preserve formatting from the original JSON, though, you'll have to either parse it yourself, or change the source to store it as a `string`.